# Functions that return Enums?

Tags: c, function, code

In Atmel ASF I found this piece of code

```
enum status_code eeprom_emulator_init(void)
{ 

enum status_code error_code = STATUS_OK;
struct nvm_config config;
struct nvm_parameters parameters;

/* Retrieve the NVM controller configuration - enable manual page writing
 * mode so that the emulator has exclusive control over page writes to
 * allow for caching */
nvm_get_config_defaults(&config);
config.manual_page_write = true;

/* Apply new NVM configuration */
do {
    error_code = nvm_set_config(&config);
} while (error_code == STATUS_BUSY);

/* Get the NVM controller configuration parameters */
nvm_get_parameters(&parameters);

/* Ensure the device fuses are configured for at least one master page row,
 * one user EEPROM data row and one spare row */
if (parameters.eeprom_number_of_pages < (3 * NVMCTRL_ROW_PAGES)) {
    return STATUS_ERR_NO_MEMORY;
}
```

As far as I know about enums they are used for variables, then how is it also used to contain instructions in above code.?

Comment: enum is a data type, not a function.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742699/returning-an-enum-from-a-function-in-c

Comment: @ScottSeidman yep, Explanations and working that I saw about enums were pretty simple, but then what is this complex usage involving struct, functions,etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `enum` doesn't contain the code. The function is an ordinary function that happens to return a value of type `enum status_code`.

You don't normally see this syntax, because most programmers would also create a `typedef` for the `enum status_code` and use that to declare the type of the function's return value.

For example:

```
typedef enum status_code status_code_t;

status_code_t eeprom_emulator_init (void)
{
    ...
```

Comment: ok, now it's clear.